# Why Apache Hadoop need to be Installed separately for Running Apache Spark...?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm learning Apache Spark, where I'm trying to run a basic Spark Program written in Java. I've installed Apache Spark (spark-2.4.3-bin-without-hadoop) downloaded from https://spark.apache.org/.

I've created a maven project in eclipse and added the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

After building the project, I've tried to run the program by setting sparkMaster=local through spark config and now I've Encountered with the following error:

> java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.

After referring some sites, I've installed hadoop-2.7.7 and added "HADOOP_HOME" to my .bash_profile.

And I'm able to execute my Spark Program!!

Now I need to know where and how Hadoop is necessary for Spark?

Comment: Because that's the default platform for Spark, I guess? And it uses Hadoop client libraries as well. And there's a standalone cluster mode as well, all documented within one or two clicks off the homepage you link to.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm using the standalone cluster mode only..., But still it requires Hadoop library. If it's the default platform, what's the purpose of Hadoop inside client? Let me know that if you are aware of it.